# Boundary equation of the trajectory of a closed curve

Tags: geometry

Are there analytical/closed form equations for the boundaries of the trajectory traced out by a closed curve (tool) in 2D plane? (The tool does not change orientation. It moves along a trajectory.)

Edit: I think I have an idea. Perhaps one can find a point on g(x,y)=0 farthest along the normal of f(x,y) = 0 for every point on the trajectory of the tool.

[image]